# Transform data from one observable using another observable in angular rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two observables: cities and addresses.  In my `addresses` array I have an object with a property `city_code` which has a value and a property `city` which is empty.  In `cities` I have objects with both properties.

How can I transform the data in `addresses`? I want to get the value for `city` from the `cities` array by matching the `city_code` and put that value into the corresponding object in `addresses`.

```
addresses$ = this.store.select(getAddresses);
cities$ = this.citiesFacade.allCities$;

function getAddressesWithCityName() {
   // some code here
}
```

Address and City:

```
export interface Address {
   city_code: string;
   city: string; // in addresses$ this property is empty and I should get it from cities$
}

export interface City{
   city_code: string;
   city: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combineLatest()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to create an observable stream that is always up to date based on multiple source streams.

Then, you can simply define `addresses$` as follows, without the need for the `getAddressesWithCityName()` method:

```
addresses$ = combineLatest([this.store.select(getAddresses), this.cities$]).pipe(
    map(([addresses, cities]) => addresses.map(a => {
        const city = cities.find(c => c.city_code === a.city_code)?.city;
        return { ...a, city };
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
    function getAddressesWithCityName(): Observable<Address[]> {
      return forkJoin([addresses$, cities$])
        .pipe(map((results: [Address[], City[]]) => {
          results[0]
            .forEach((address: Address) => address.city = (results[1]
              .find((city: City) => city.city_code === address.city_code) as City)?.city);
          return results[0];
        }));
    }
```